# Usar ONCHANGE en datepicker de gijgo

Tags: php

Tengo esta entrada, en un formulario. Pero el uso de onchange="submit()" me invalida la selección.

```
      <div class="form-group">
           <div class='input-group date'>
                <span class="input-group-addon" title="Fecha visita"><i class='fa fa-calendar pr-1'></i></span>
                <input id="datepicker" class="form-control text-center" onchange="submit()" name="inputfec" value="<?php echo $feccot; ?>">
           </div>
           <script>
           $('#datepicker').datepicker({
           locale: 'es-es',
           uiLibrary: 'bootstrap4',
           format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'});               
          </script>
     </div>
```

Como hacer uso de una función cada que cambie de fecha. Sin utilizar un botón.

Answer (score 0):

Con jquery lo puedes hacer de esta manera:

```
  <div class="form-group">
       <div class='input-group date'>
            <span class="input-group-addon" title="Fecha visita"><i class='fa fa-     calendar pr-1'></i></span>
            <input id="datepicker" class="form-control text-center"  name="inputfec" value="<?php echo $feccot; ?>">
       </div>
       <script>
       $('#datepicker').datepicker({
       locale: 'es-es',
       uiLibrary: 'bootstrap4',
       format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'});
       $('#datePicker').on('change', function () {
            $('#formId').submit();
       })               
      </script>
 </div>
```

Comment: Lo he probado pero no funciona